# Вопрос об ООП (C#, Java)

Tags: c#, java

Добрый вечер ! Не могу разобраться вот есть код :

```
public class Ax {}
public class Bx:Ax {} 
class Program {
    void Main() {  
        Ax ax = new Bx()
    }  
}
```

Почему это работает, если я вызываю конструктор класса Bx, но создаю обьект класса Ах ?

Comment: потому что Bx унаследован от Ax, а следовательно Bx также является Ax. Учите ООП, это одна из элементарных основ

Comment: @DreamChild я исхожу немного из других побуждений - считаю, что в будущем ответ понадобится кому-нибудь. Вероятность того, что в качестве ответа будет зачтен комментарий слишком мала - все потонет потом в потоке битов/байтов. А то что ответ будет увиден - вероятность выше. Именно поэтому я противник комментариев в качестве ответов.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Почему это работает, если я вызываю конструктор класса Bx, но создаю обьект класса Ах ?

Вы не создаете объект класса Ax, а создаете Bx при этом ссылку на созданный объект присваиваете объекту типа Ax.

В свою очередь присвоение `ax=new Bx()` валидно посколько Bx является потомком Ax

**Update**

Однако: `bx = new Ax() //неверно!!!`

Программист всегда человек, но человек - увы не всегда программист!

Comment: @Barmaley, начинаю немного понимать спасибо. То есть я создал обьект Вх, но ссылка на него будет хранится в обьекте Ах и когда я создам Ах то буду иметь содержимое класса (поля\методы) как Ах так и Вх ?

Comment: @AnderFace нет это совсем не так. Представьте лучше аналогию из реального мира. Есть сущность "человек" - у него две руки, две ноги, он может есть, спать и говорить. Теперь представьте еще одну сущность - "Программист" - он может писать код. Однако "Программист" одновременно является и человеком тоже (по крайней мере чаще всего так и бывает. Не помню ни одной собаки-программиста). Поэтому "Программист", будучи "Человеком" также может есть, спать и говорить и имеет две руки и две ноги. Так вот в вашем случае "Программист" - это Bx, а "Человек" - это Ax

Comment: @DreamChild, большое спасибо

Comment: @DreamChild Не по теме, но я встречал таких программистов -- ну чисто собаки.

Comment: >Не по теме, но я встречал таких программистов -- ну чисто собаки

@alexlz, все понимают, но сказать не могут? Или в смысле, друзья человека?)

Comment: @DreamChild имелись в виду друзья человека, хотя и особи первого типа вполне встречаются.